# Which open source program is similar to the Linux "dialog" command?

Tags: linux, bash, user-interface, dialog, tput

Dialog command is great command to view GUI dialog box 
But the non positive of the dialog is that we cant to locate the GUI window on the top of the screen or in the lower screen
Dialog always show the dialog GUI in the central of the screen

First I want to say that I want to use the tail box function ( this dialog make tail on the file that running ) , and tail box exsist in the dialog option , but I cant use it because what I explained here

My target is to show the tail box window down in the screen and not in the centeral
So

I searched and found some other open source that similer to dialog as Yad , Whiptail , zenite and so on
But I not sure if the other open source have the option to locate the tail box window in the lower of the screen

Please some one advice me which other open source have the option to locate the GUI dialog in every location on the screen

example from dialog command

```
        dialog --tailboxbg    <file> <height> <width>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a different dialog command; you just need to review the documentation:

```
dialog --begin <y> <x> --tailboxbg ...
```

Comment: WOW THIS IS WHAT I WANT THX ALLOT ( +1 )